# Writing resp.Body to a local file sometimes is incomplete

Tags: file, go, http, io

I'm writing a program that massively performs REST calls to some endpoint, then caching the result as-is in a local file, and returns a file pointer for consumption by the caller.

99% of the time, my code works fine, but I randomly get a cache file that doesn't contain the whole body of the request.

The code looks like this, and the caller only calls `readFromCache()` like so :

```golang
    file, err := CacheProxy{}.readFromCache(url, path.Join("CACHE", a.Hostname, a.ID, s))
```

```golang
func (c CacheProxy) readFromCache(url string, p string) (io.ReadCloser, error) {
    c.makeDirectory(p)
    file, err := os.Open(p)
    if err != nil {
        // Can't open the file if it doesn't exists, readFromURL then
        return c.readFromURL(url, p)
    }
    return file, nil
}

func (c CacheProxy) readFromURL(url string, p string) (io.ReadCloser, error) {
    client := http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        log.Errorf("Cant read from URL : %s", err)
        return nil, err
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()

    out, err := os.Create(p)
    if err != nil {
        log.Errorf("Unable to open file : %s", err)
        return nil, err
    }

    writer := bufio.NewWriter(out)
    _, err = io.Copy(writer, resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Errorf("Unable to copy file : %s", err)
        return nil, err
    }

    writer.Flush()

    _, err = out.Seek(0, 0)
    if err != nil {
        log.Errorf("Unable seek to beginning : %s", err)
        return nil, err
    }
    return out, nil
}
```

I also tried to add `out.Sync()` without success

If I bypass the cache and return `resp.Body` directly in `readFromURL()` it doesn't seem to cause any issues.

The reason I'm using `io.Copy()` is for memory efficiency.

Note that I return a `io.ReadCloser` and it's the caller responsibility to call `Close()` on it.

I should also add that this function is called from different threads but no call would point to the same file so I don't think I'm writing twice at the same location and overwriting the file while writing it.

The part that writes the result to the file seems relatively simple and I'm looking to understand why at any point the output would be truncated.

I think I catching and logging every single `error` that matters. I would assume `io.Copy()` returns an error if the stream in unexpectedly closed by the remote server ?

But in that case, I would have exceptions even when return `resp.Body` directly (bypass cache), which is not the case

**[Update 1]**

The following code works without any issue :

```golang
func (c CacheProxy) readFromURL(url string, p string) (io.ReadCloser, error) {
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        log.Errorf("Cant read from URL : %s", err)
        return nil, err
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()

    if resp.StatusCode != 200 {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("ResultCode != 200 (%d), aborting", resp.StatusCode)
    }

    body, err := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Errorf("Error while reading body : %s", err)
        return nil, err
    }

    os.WriteFile(p, body, 0600)

    out, err := os.Open(p)
    if err != nil {
        log.Errorf("Cannot reopen file : %s", err)
        return nil, err
    }
    return out, nil
}
```

Which makes me wonder what I'm doing wrong with `io.Copy()` and `bufio.Writer`, I don't like that currently I have to load all content in memory just to write it.

**[Update 2]**

I tried to use `file.ReadFrom()` instead of `io.Copy()` and the same problem happens :

```golang
func (c CacheProxy) readFromURL(url string, p string) (io.ReadCloser, error) {
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        log.Errorf("Cant read from URL : %s", err)
        return nil, err
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()

    if resp.StatusCode != 200 {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("ResultCode != 200 (%d), aborting", resp.StatusCode)
    }

    out, err := os.Create(p)
    if err != nil {
        log.Errorf("Unable to open file : %s", err)
        return nil, err
    }
    out.ReadFrom(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Errorf("Unable to read stream : %s", err)
        return nil, err
    }
    err = out.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Errorf("Error while closing file : %s", err)
        return nil, err
    }

    out, err = os.Open(p)
    if err != nil {
        log.Errorf("Cannot reopen file : %s", err)
        return nil, err
    }
    return out, nil
}
```

**[Update 3]**

It might be interesting to report that sometimes, the files are not truncated, but missing the *beginning*, the end is fine, which seems extremely odd. I think I'm doing something wrong with my threads, but I'm told http.Client is fully thread safe and I should be able to read different bodies from different requests in different threads consistently.

Comment: You’re not closing `out` here, are you certain it’s being completely flushed to disk?

Comment: As JimB already pointed out: Without `Close()` ing the file nothing might ever get written (regardless of Sync). And (unrelated) reuse you http.Client.

Comment: Even though `out` isn’t closed or flushed to disk, would it really matter ? I’m returning the file pointer to the client after the `Copy()` operation so it should be the full copy of ˋresp.Body` usable in memory and I wouldn’t care if it’s fully written to disk later on when ˋClose()` is called (which it is)

Comment: if `io.Copy` errors, your code returns `nil` (instead of the the file) and `writer.Flush()` is not called. Do you confirm that you never see an error message `"Unable to copy to file :"` when you run your code ?

Comment: Editing with the latest test without using `io.Copy()` which works.

Comment: @LeGEC Yes I'm returning errors up the chain and I would have seen it in the logs, thanks !

Comment: @YannBizeul, without a timely Close call the next request for the same file may read only the partially cached result. There’s also no synchronization here, what happens with concurrent calls to the same path?

Comment: There shouldn’t be any concurrent calls to the same file, during a test round I’m only writing each file once and read it once. 
In Update 2 you can see I experience the same problems using ReadFrom, closing the file, and opening it again. 

In other words, I’m never opening a file without it being closed before. I’m either seeking it or opening it after the close and both fails. 

The only thing that works seems to be using ReadAll to get body content and write that.